# Entity Framework 6 Code First - Multiple Model/Configurations

Tags: frameworks, entity, sql-server-ce

After many fruitless searches I have decided to put my head above the parapet. *I am building an EF6 code first application* for an embedded device.

I have successfully followed many references to enable me to create *[SQL CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)* files in the folder locations I need.

However, I need to have two separate models running at the same time

1 - **Admin model deals with common things like user logins and generic details.**

2 - **Project specific model where the real work gets done.**

> The concept is that the Admin database file resides and remains on the
>   device, but the project database file can be passed from one device to
>   another.

Is it possible to have two different model databases open at the same time in [EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/)?

If so is there a good reference site that my search terms have not yet found that will offer advice appropriate to my use-case?

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve my own question now having found a new article to refer to [Multiple Model EF 6 Data points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn948104.aspx)

Read the article on how to solve my question and other variants of similar problems. The key to solving this problem was to specify separate folders for each context migration when commanding the NuGet Package Manager Console. Then in the initialiser for each context, refer to the configuration in the appropriate migration folder. Rather than repeating here, please see the article on MSDN I linked to as all the information I needed was in there, plus lots more.